# PHP file download gives garbage for anything BUT .pdf files

Tags: php, apache, freebsd

I am having an issue in which the only filetype capable of being downloaded correctly from the server is ".pdf".  Other files of other file types exist in the same location, upload perfectly fine, have the correct permissions, and load just fine when I scp them off to my local machine.  I can't show the entirety of the code involved since this is paid software, but honestly it seems that the problem shouldn't even lie in the code itself...

I've tried re-writing the first function below with something similar to this: http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/php-file-download and then simply feeding it the correct values to make it pick specific files from the server.  The files downloaded the same either way.  They would show up as the correct file type with the correct name and even the correct size, but they would not open as anything but garbage values (unless a PDF).  It is an apache server running freeBSD 8.2-RELEASE.

Either way, this is part of a class that is included by the code following it:

```
1600     function download_file($fileDir,$fileName,$instance_name)
1601     {
1602         $fileString=$fileDir.'/'.$fileName; // combine the path and file
1603         // translate file name properly for Internet Explorer.
1604     if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "MSIE"))
1605     {
1606           $instance_name = preg_replace('/\./', '%2e', $instance_name,  substr_count($instance_name, '.') - 1);
1607     }
1608     // make sure the file exists before sending headers
1609 
1610     if(!$fdl=@fopen($fileString,'r'))
1611         {
1612            die("Cannot Open File!");
1613         }
1614     else
1615         {
1616           header("Cache-Control: ");// leave blank to avoid IE errors
1617           header("Pragma: ");// leave blank to avoid IE errors
1618           header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
1619           header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$instance_name."\"");
1620           header("Content-length:".(string)(filesize($fileString)));
1621           sleep(1);
1622           fpassthru($fdl);
1623         }
1624     }
```

And now the code that uses it:

```
63         function download_att($supp_obj,$a_predefined) 64         {
65 
66             $get_vars=$a_predefined['get'];
67             $att_id=$get_vars['att_id'];
68             $article_attachment=$supp_obj->prefix_table("article_attachment");
69             $sql="select * from $article_attachment where att_id=$att_id";
70             $a_attach=$supp_obj->get_a_line($sql);
71 
72             $instance_name=$a_attach['attachment_name'];
73             $att_name_arr=split("\.",$instance_name);
74
75             list($n,$ext)=split("\.", $instance_name);
76
77
78             $fileName="kb_".$a_attach['article_id']."_".$att_id.".".$ext;
79             $fileDir="plugins/knowledgebase/attachments";
80             $supp_obj->download_file($fileDir,$fileName,$instance_name);
81         }
82 //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
83 
84     if($a_predefined['get']['act']=="artattach")
85     {
86         download_att($supp_obj,$a_predefined);
87         exit;
88     }
```

Comment: And are these files in the correct format on the server?

Comment: Disable output compression of your webserver (and caching), as well as output compression on the PHP side. Then check if the problem still exists.

Comment: Still occurs even with output compression disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What types are the other files?  Are they supposed to be served as octet-streams as you're doing?:

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
```

If, for example, you serve a text file with that header then how the browser interprets that file (or, more accurately, that response) may not be guaranteed.

Comment: The other files can be of any type.  I assume there's no generic content-type... so I should be generating a different content-type section dependent on the file extension.  What I don't understand is how this "supposedly" worked before I was here, and mysteriously broke a few weeks before I started.  The code never included anything which would have determined a dynamic content type.

Comment: Either way, shouldn't octet-stream simply load the default application for that extension or at least allow me to select the correct application to load it with.  This shouldn't actually be modifying the file itself...  Setting the content type to msword and trying to open a .doc file still results in garbage values.

Comment: @Ryan Baker: It's an interesting question.  Maybe the client browser is writing the file in a broken way on the client side because of the content type?  What happens if you serve a plain text file and open it in notepad?  In a hex editor?

Comment: I will try with a hex editor on monday, but it still shows garbage values in its corresponding editor (regardless of the file type/application).  This also occurs across multiple systems.  I have tested it on a Windows box (xp and 7) as well as MacOSX 10.6.7.  The only thing that would seem to make sense is some error in the configuration of apache/php... But I have no clue where to start looking.  Either way, I won't be working on this again until Monday.  If I come up with anything I will update this question then.

Answer (score 0):

Are the other files perhaps not of type application/octet-stream?

Make sure you send the correct mime-type header.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no blank lines or anything but PHP in your download file, as this will default the mimetype to `Content-type: text/html` and add additional garbage data to the file you download.